# Storing the address of a string in an array of strings

Tags: c

I'm having some issues with storing an address of a specific value in an array of strings to a pointer and printing it out.  Please excuse the bad variable names, they are just for the example.

```
char **code;                      // code is an array of 100 strings of length 8 characters
code = malloc (100*sizeof(*code));
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    code[i]=malloc(8*sizeof(**code));
}

char **r;                        // r is an array of 16 strings of 32 characters
r = malloc (16*sizeof(*r));
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    r[i] = malloc(32*sizeof(**r));

char *a;                         // a is a pointer to a string

a = (char *) &r[13];             // point a to value at r[13]

*a = (char *)&code[100];         // trying to assign the value of r[13] to the address of code[100]   

printf("Code 100 Add: %p a Val: %i\n", &code[100], *sp);  // trying to check values.
```

I'm trying to assign the value of a (which points to r[13], so assign value of r[13]) to the value of the Address of the string at code[100].  Is even a string of 32 characters the best way to do this?

Appreciate any help,
Gareth

Comment: This example has a lot of flaws. Examples: not casting the result of malloc, assigning a (char *) to both (a) and (*a). Can you post real code?  What is it that you are trying to do?  If you are having problems compiling - start with the compiler errors.  If you are having problems trying to get it to run - please post code that compiles and start with a good debugger and smaller arrays so that you can see what is going on at each step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = (char *) &r[13];             // point a to value at r[13]
```

Turn on your compiler warnings, and pay attention to what the compiler tell you when you remove this cast.  You shouldn't need any casts in this code.

The type of `r` is `char**` and so the type of `r[13]` is `char*`, and the type of `&r[13]` is `char**`, which you're assigning to a `char*`.

P.s., next time please also include the actual error you receive vs what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a string, use `strncpy`. Don't copy the pointer value directly because you will free it twice later this way (among other problems).

Comment: So something like:
`strcpy(a, &code[100]);`  
It still doesn't seem to store the correct value according the the printf

Comment: You don't need the extra `&`, because `code[100]` already points to the beginning of a string.

Comment: Safest is `strncpy(a, code[100], 31); a[31] = '\0';` You should use a constant instead of 32 literally, of course.

Answer (score 0):

`&r[13]` is not a pointer to char.

You just need to

```
r[13] = code[100]
```

I do agree with Frederik that you should be careful when `free()`-ing the allocated memory since you now have two pointers pointing at the same memory block. If you prefer to follows his advice, try the following:

```
strncpy(r[13], code[100], 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than assigning a pointer to a memory address, you're going to want to copy the data at that memory address using [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/).

Answer (score 0):

With definition of `char *a;` the `*a` on the left-hand side of an assignment becomes an [*lvalue*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29) of type `char`. You *can* assign pointer values there as integers, as in square peg into a round hole, though it does not make much sense. To copy strings use [`str[nl]cpy(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strcpy.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

I hate to ask a question during someone else's question... but shouldn't the char array setup/malloc calls be something more like this? Isn't he allocating too much with sizeof(**code)? And then... if it's for 8 characters... won't we want 9 to make room for '\0'?

```
char **code;                      // code is an array of 100 strings of length 8 characters
code = (char**) malloc (100*sizeof(char*));
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
   code[i] = (char*)malloc(9*sizeof(char));
}
```